# Which datatype can be used to insert this record in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to insert a row:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Worker] ([Worker_id], [FIRST_NAME], [LAST_NAME],[SALARY], [JOINING_DATE], [DEPARTMENT])
VALUES (001, 'Monika', 'Arora', 100000, 2014-02-20 09:00:00, 'HR')
```

I used `DateTime` / `SmallDateTime` / `Date` datatypes to insert this row using

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Worker]
    ALTER COLUMN JOINING_DATE SmallDateTime
```

But I got an error

> Incorrect syntax near '09'.

Please help me with this

Answer (score 3):

you need to put the date inside quotes

Try this

```
Insert Into [dbo].[Worker] ([Worker_id],[FIRST_NAME],[LAST_NAME],[SALARY],[JOINING_DATE],[DEPARTMENT])
values (001, 'Monika' , 'Arora', 100000,'2014-02-20 09:00:00','HR')
```

Comment: Ahh!! My Bad thank you for your help